# Find last commit in Git repo that contains a certain string pattern

Tags: git, awk, grep

I want to go back in time to the last commit which contained code such as, "ThisClass(object):".  That code was subsequently removed from the project in a later commit.

I thought about using git bisect + grep/awk-ing.  I've also heard that git grep may allow you to do this sort of thing, though I can't figure out the right command in the man pages.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the -S (search) argument to `git log`:

```
git log -S 'ThisClass(object):'
```

Comment: Yep, that's the one.  Thanks Ethan

Comment: This seems to search the commit comments. Seems that the OP wanted to search the code for a string.

Comment: Incorrect, Doo Dah: the -S option explicitly searches for commits that add or delete the search string (not in comments).